# Is it possible to use the mitigation process on a teleportation circuit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, noise, teleportation, error-mitigation

Is it possible to use the mitigation process on a teleportation circuit? Sorry, i'm still starting, if someone can get me out of this doubt, I would appreciate it. The circuit I'm trying to make this process is similar to the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you could do is measure the bits, and then possibly flip the answer based on whether a drawn random number is less than the error rate associated with the outcome, i.e the error rates of measuring 0 but really given a 1, and measuring 1 but really given a 0.  However, doing this on actual HW is a bit more tricky.  Namely all of the logic needs to be fast so that decoherence doesn't kill your qubits.  So in that case I guess one would draw the number of required random values ahead of time and store them on the FPGA used in the control so that the inequality and bit-flip can be done as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is meaningful to apply Quantum Error Correction (QEC) on post-measurement result with respect to the advance knowledge about physical behavior of qubits and quantum gates on QPU chip. Applying QEC on qubits while they are actively manipulated by a quantum algorithm (though quantum gates) will intentionally disturb the computation.